# moment.js - difference between 2 dates is off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to find the difference between today and a date in the future (number of days) using moment.js.

But the response is always off by 1-2 days.

For instance, trying to find the # of days between today (15 June) and 11th July gives me 25 days whereas it should be 27 days.

Here's what I am using

`moment(expiryDate).diff(moment(), 'days');`

`expiryDate` is a string of the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

I am assuming the difference is because the dates themselves are not included? But nothing in the moment.js document suggests this. Neither did I find anything by which I can tell the library to calculate the difference inclusive of the dates.

Answer (score 1):

**This should do the trick**

```js
console.log(
  moment("2020-07-11", 'YYYY-MM-DD').diff(moment("2020-06-15", 'YYYY-MM-DD'),"days")
) // outputs 26 (which is correct)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```